# Can I return multiple unmatched results from a single SQL join without using a cursor?

Tags: sql, join, exists, repeat

I have two tables.

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID, EmployeeName, DocumentType
```

and

**DocumentType**

```
DocumentTypeID, DocumentType
```

There are Multiple Employees and Multiple DocumentTypes.

For each employee, I am trying to display which DocumentTypes do not exist.

I cant seem to do this for each EmployeeID/Employee Name. 
I can only get a list of DocumentTypes that dont exist for ALL employees.

Can I do this without a cursor going through each EmployeeID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT Better version**

```
select distinct e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName, t.DocumentTypeID, t.DocumentType
from Employee e
cross join DocumentType t
left join Employee e2 on e2.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and t.DocumentTypeID = e2.DocumentTypeID
where e2.EmployeeID is null
```

**Original** - 
This works but doesn't feel like the most elegant solution

```
select distinct e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName, dt.DocumentTypeID, dt.DocumentType
from Employee e
outer apply (
    select * from DocumentType t
    where not exists (
        select 1 
        from Employee e2 
        where e2.DocumentTypeID = t.DocumentTypeID 
        and e2.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID)
) dt
```

Comment: @SimonStainmagen Cool but don't forget to accept and upvote answers that have helped...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for data something like this

```
EmployeeID EmployeeName DocumentTypeNotMapped
1          abc          doctype1, doctype3, doctype4
2          def          doctype3, doctype2, doctype7
```

Using the query

```
SELECT ET.EmployeeID, ET.EmployeeName,
SELECT LEFT(DocumentType, LEN(DocumentType) - 1)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DocumentType + ', '
    FROM DocumentTypeTable 
    WHERE DocumentType != ET.DocumentType 
    FOR XML PATH ('')
  ) D (DocumentType)
FROM EmployeeTable ET
```

Comment: if the employee document type mapping table have one many  mapping then use distinct with the employee id to get the desired result

Comment: yeah checkout the 'markup' help http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help but generally 4 spaces before code lines

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using sql server

```
;with cte as (
select E.EmployeeID, E.DocumentType,D.DocumentTypeID from Employee E
 left outer join Document D
on E.DocumentType<>D.DocumentTypeID),
cte1 as (select EmployeeID,DocumentTypeID  from cte
group by  EmployeeID,DocumentTypeID
having count(*)>1)
select * from cte1
union all
select EmployeeID,DocumentTypeID from cte where EmployeeID not in
(select EmployeeID from cte1)
order by EmployeeID,DocumentTypeID
```